# I made a Tic-tac-toe game with JavaScript, but I don’t know the add code

Tags: javascript, html

All basic program code is implemented and works well.
However, I would like to include a function that clears all cell values and restarts them when all nine cell compartments are filled.
I put my code on the tin, and it’s not working.
I’d like you to give me some advice on adding this function.

```js
let table = document.querySelector('table');
let cell = [];
let line = [];
let text = document.querySelector('p');
let turn = 'X';
let chance = [];

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  const lineEach = document.createElement('tr');

  cell.push([]);
  line.push(lineEach);
  table.appendChild(lineEach);

  for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    const cellEach = document.createElement('td');

    cell[i].push(cellEach);
    lineEach.appendChild(cellEach);
    cellEach.addEventListener('click', start);
  }
}

function start(event) {
  let numLineEach = line.indexOf(event.target.parentNode);
  let numCellEachEach = cell[numLineEach].indexOf(event.target);

  if (cell[numLineEach][numCellEachEach].textContent === '') {
    cell[numLineEach][numCellEachEach].textContent = turn;

    let result = false;

    if (cell[numLineEach][0].textContent === turn && cell[numLineEach][1].textContent === turn && cell[numLineEach][2].textContent === turn) {
      result = true;
    }

    if (cell[0][numCellEachEach].textContent === turn && cell[1][numCellEachEach].textContent === turn && cell[2][numCellEachEach].textContent === turn) {
      result = true;
    }

    if (numLineEach - numCellEachEach === 0) {
      if (cell[0][0].textContent === turn && cell[1][1].textContent === turn && cell[2][2].textContent === turn) {
        result = true;
      }
    }

    if (Math.abs(numLineEach - numCellEachEach) === 2 || Math.abs(numLineEach - numCellEachEach) === 0) {
      if (cell[0][2].textContent === turn && cell[1][1].textContent === turn && cell[2][0].textContent === turn) {
        result = true;
      }
    }

    if (result) {
      text.innerText = turn + " turn win!";
      cell.forEach(function(lineEach) {
        lineEach.forEach(function(cellEach) {
          cellEach.innerText = '';
        })
      })
    } else {
      if (turn === 'X') {
        turn = "O";
      } else {
        turn = 'X';
      }
    }
  } else {
    text.innerText = 'no!';
  }
}

/*
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    chance.push(cell[i][j].textContent);
    var number = chance.indexOf('');
    if (number === -1) {
      text.innerText = " no winner";
      cell.forEach(function(lineEach) {
        lineEach.forEach(function(cellEach) {
          cellEach.innerText = '';
        })
      })

    }
  }
}
*/
```

```css
table, tr, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

td {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px
}
```

```html
<table></table>
<p></p>
```

Note that I can’t speak English, so I’m asking this question using a translator.

Comment: What do you mean by “cell compartments”? Is it just “cells”? And what do you mean by “tin”?

Answer (score 0):

you don't really need a new function.  Just modify your start function a little like this:

although, if you wanted to create a new game button that would restart the game a new function would make sense.  Let me know if that's what you want to do

```js
let table = document.querySelector('table');
let cell = [];
let line = [];
let text = document.querySelector('p');
let turn = 'X';
let chance = [];

var nineCnt = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    const lineEach = document.createElement('tr');
    cell.push([]);
    line.push(lineEach);
    table.appendChild(lineEach);
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        const cellEach = document.createElement('td');
        cell[i].push(cellEach);
        lineEach.appendChild(cellEach);
        cellEach.addEventListener('click', start);
    }
}
function start(event) {
    let numLineEach = line.indexOf(event.target.parentNode);
    let numCellEachEach = cell[numLineEach].indexOf(event.target);
    if (cell[numLineEach][numCellEachEach].textContent === '') {
        cell[numLineEach][numCellEachEach].textContent = turn;
        
        
        
        nineCnt++;
        if(nineCnt == 9){
           var tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td')
           for(let i = 0; i< 9; i++){
              tds[i].innerHTML = '';
           }
        }        
        
        
        let result = false;
        if (cell[numLineEach][0].textContent === turn && cell[numLineEach][1].textContent === turn && cell[numLineEach][2].textContent === turn) {
            result = true;
        }
        if (cell[0][numCellEachEach].textContent === turn && cell[1][numCellEachEach].textContent === turn && cell[2][numCellEachEach].textContent === turn) {
            result = true;
        }
        if (numLineEach - numCellEachEach === 0) {
            if (cell[0][0].textContent === turn && cell[1][1].textContent === turn && cell[2][2].textContent === turn) {
                result = true;
            }
        }
        if (Math.abs(numLineEach - numCellEachEach) === 2 || Math.abs(numLineEach - numCellEachEach) === 0) {
            if (cell[0][2].textContent === turn && cell[1][1].textContent === turn && cell[2][0].textContent === turn) {
                result = true;
            }
        }
        if (result) {
            text.innerText = turn + " turn win!";
            cell.forEach(function (lineEach) {
                lineEach.forEach(function (cellEach) {
                    cellEach.innerText = '';
                })
            })
        }
        else {
            if (turn === 'X') {
                turn = "O";
            }
            else {
                turn = 'X';
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        text.innerText = 'no!';
    }
}

/*
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        chance.push(cell[i][j].textContent);
        var number = chance.indexOf('');
        if(number === -1){
            text.innerText =  " no winner";
            cell.forEach(function (lineEach) {
                lineEach.forEach(function (cellEach) {
                    cellEach.innerText = '';
                })
            })

        }
    }
}
*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        table,
        tr,
        td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 2rem;
            font-weight: bolder;
        }

        td {
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <table></table>
    <p></p>
    <script src='tictactoe.js'></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Aha, that's a awesome way. Maybe I thought it was too complicated.

Comment: glad it works for you.  please accept answer